# Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tailwind-css

I installed the new tailwindcss version 2.0 and I've got the following error. I tried to uninstall postcss and tailwindcss but it does not work. Need help.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
    at Processor.normalize (/Users/niklas/Desktop/Privat/Projekte/nifoschool-frontend/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:153:15)
    at new Processor (/Users/niklas/Desktop/Privat/Projekte/nifoschool-frontend/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:56:25)
    at postcss (/Users/niklas/Desktop/Privat/Projekte/nifoschool-frontend/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:55:10)
    at /Users/niklas/Desktop/Privat/Projekte/nifoschool-frontend/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js:140:12

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--6-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/util/SlideInfo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 4:14-393 14:3-18:5 15:22-401
 @ ./src/components/util/SlideInfo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./src/components/util/SlideInfo.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Grades.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Grades.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/Grades.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://172.20.12.3:8081&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Here is my package.json

````
  "name": "nifo-school",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "@ivanv/vue-collapse-transition": "^0.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "electron": "^8.0.0",
    "electron-drag": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^=8.0",
    "react-collapse": "^5.0.1",
    "summernote": "^0.8.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
    "v-click-outside": "^3.1.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-html-editor": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.22.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss": "^=8.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,vue}": [
      "vue-cli-service lint",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}```


Thanks for help
````

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You're integrating Tailwind with a tool that relies on an older version of PostCSS. You can use this doc https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

Comment: Vue 3 is one thing that does not yet have postcss 8 support. The guide above works great without hassle.

Comment: I get the following errors: `npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree`,`npm ERR! Found: tailwindcss@2.0.2` Any help?

Comment: I'm using Vue 3.0.7, which should have support for PostCSS 8, but I still get this error. My package-lock.json shows that the PostCSS is at v8.2.7, and I can't install the compat build because it conflicts with the PostCSS 8 requirement in @vue/compiler-sfc 3.0.7.

Comment: I'm using Vue2, and this workaround doesn't work.

Comment: In my case I was using Yarn 2+, which also doesn't work. Downgrading Yarn for this project to 1 solved the problem.

Comment: Vue version 3.0.6 began supporting PostCSS 8 (see 3rd point in the GitHub documentation, under "features" at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#306-2021-02-24 ). Even so, I'm STILL having "Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8" - this is a question on Stack at https://stackoverflow.com/q/69109763/1459653

Comment: that link seems to pointer no longer to anything related to compatibility anymore.

Answer (score 73):

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

then

```
vue add tailwind
```

to use the vue cli plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-tailwind

Comment: Confirmed working with latest Vue3 + Typescript.

Comment: Great for those using vue cli. I used vite procedure that was why I got that error.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm getting `Cannot find module postcss-import`

Comment: @The-null-Pointer- I had the same error trying this solution. I Had to let the command generate a new tailwind.config.js, although I already had  one. Then it worked.

Answer (score 67):

worked for me :

```
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Comment: I get the following errors: `npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree`,`npm ERR! Found: tailwindcss@2.0.2` Any help?

Comment: thanks ,,, this is a live saver ,, fixed my issue with laravel breeze installation

Comment: A thread on Tailwind's GitHub (sorry, no link) suggests each ```^``` may need to be escaped with an ```\``` before each instance of ```^```

Comment: Legend. I ran `npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer` first but this sorted it for me. Build was successful. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Works well with Vue3 + TS

Answer (score 37):

This solution below should work perfectly.

Run the following commands. Remove the `-D` from the `npm uninstall` command if you originally installed tailwind etc as regular dependencies rather than dev dependencies.

```
npm uninstall -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat  postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Comment: The second line errors out with Error code E404...
I'll edit your post to properly reflect what it should be, In future though, Be more explanative in your answers

Comment: It's a good idea to install these with `--save-dev` or `-D` since they're only dev dependencies.

Comment: Second line - npm ERR! Cannot read property 'name' of null

Comment: The second line has an extra `@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat` that causes the problem. I'll edit the answer to remove it.

Answer (score 15):

Uninstall Tailwind and re-install using the compatibility build instead

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Comment: they need to fix this thing soon. I ecnounter the same when I was trying to use it last week with vue cli project and today with parcelJS project. Thank you

Comment: A thread on Tailwind's GitHub (sorry, no link) suggests each ```^``` may need to be escaped with an ```\``` before each instance of ```^```

Answer (score 14):

I was getting dependency tree error when I try uninstall and install with compact version. So I had to install with `yarn` instead and it works.

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Comment: For yarn 2, 
```yarn add tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2 postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is now out of date.

As of v2.0, Tailwind CSS depends on PostCSS 8. The previously accepted answer states how to *downgrade to PostCSS 8*

Instead please do the following to get everything running on all the latest versions

`yarn add @storybook/addon-postcss`

Then edit your `.storybook/main.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-postcss",
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require("postcss"),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-postcss

@dlporter98

Comment: You need storybook for tailwind?

Comment: Not everyone is running storybook who's seeing this error (i'm one of them)....

Answer (score 12):

you have to `uninstall` all  these

`npm uninstall autoprefixer postcss tailwindcss`

Then run this command, it's will generate `tailwind.css` file automatically

```
vue add tailwind
```

Comment: If you run into issues, you may need to use our PostCSS 7 compatibility build instead.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

Answer (score 9):

**With Vue 3 and Tailwindcss 3**

1. Create `tailwind.config.js`
2. Create `postcss.config.js`
3. Add following in `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: './tailwind.config.js'
    }
  }
}
```

The above configuration works fine with latest postcss, autoprefixer, vue 3 and tailwind 3

Answer (score 7):

To resolve this error, uninstall Tailwind and re-install using the compatibility build instead:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Solution from [Tailwind documentation v2](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build)

Comment: This solution indeed worked for my environment.

Comment: Does this fix the issue and allow for Tailwind 3?

Comment: It is getting ridiculous. 2022, and it is still kind of broken?

Comment: There is no need to downgrade to `PostCSS 7`, you can now easily get this working with `PostCSS 8` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605148/840897

Answer (score 5):

The above solution fixed TaildWindCss PostCss issue, but I faced another error, which is :

`TypeError: getProcessedPlugins is not a function`

The Solution for is to **upgrade Node version**, in my case I upgraded from v10 to v15 which fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Oddly I had this issue on one dev machine . . . but not the other, with identical package.json file, and using identical node/npm (15.5/7.3).  I deleted node_modules, reinstalled.  Did not fix it.

Final fix, which is bizarre, is after the node module reinstall, all I did was:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss
```

then

```
npm i tailwindcss --save-dev
```

(note, not using the compatibility package) and it worked fine.  I do have to use `--legacy-peer-deps` when re-installing the node_modules, so somehow the order of installation mattered in my scenario . . .

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue using laravel 8, So Try uninstalling tailwind using "npm uninstall tailwindcss" and install it back using

npm install tailwindcss@compat

then run "npx tailwindcss init" if you don't have the tailwing.config.js file

after then run npm run watch.

still follow up the laravel documentation for more when you get stuck
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#tailwindcss

Comment: This did not work for me on laravel 8, however this did: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

Answer (score 3):

For those upgrading to Tailwind 3, and experiencing this issue, [the following instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#it-just-isn-t-working-properly) from Tailwind's own troubleshooting are what fixed it for me.

Specifically, changing your start and build scripts:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run start:css\" \"react-scripts start\"",
"start:css": "tailwindcss -o src/tailwind.css --watch",
"build": "tsc && npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
"build:css": "NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss -o src/tailwind.css -m",
```

You'll have to install `concurrently` and `npm-run-all`, though.

The following is my `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

This will mean that you'll have to import `tailwind.css` instead of `index.css` in your index file `index.{tsx,js}` for the project.

And if this worked for you, keep in mind you might no longer need `@craco/craco` installed.

Comment: Yes this worked for me. thanks. also need to follow this steps if setup was done using postCSS previously.  Right now need to use tailwindCLI to do the setup.

`Note that Tailwind CSS v3.0 requires PostCSS 8, and no longer supports PostCSS 7. If you can’t upgrade to PostCSS 8, we recommend using Tailwind CLI instead of installing Tailwind as a PostCSS plugin.`

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a Mac using VueJS 3 (@vue/cli 4.5.11). For me the following two commands solved the issue:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

This installed:

- tailwindcss 2.1.1
- postcss 8.2.10
- autoprefixer 10.2.5

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
running "npm install tailwindcss postcss"
and "npm install tailwindcss autoprefixer"

this seperates installation of postcss and autoprefixer independently.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and was still having `TypeError: getProcessedPlugins is not a function` error. What fixed the issue for me was upgrading the nodejs version.

To check the installed node version

```
node -v
```

my node version was `v10.23.0` and was using Ubuntu. I upgraded to `v14.15.4`.

Here is how I upgraded node

```
sudo apt update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
node -v
```

also I cleaned the cache to be more sure

```
npm cache clean -f
```

After upgrading I deleted node_modules folder inside project. ran `npm install` and then ran `npm run dev` inside the project folder.

This is the only solution that worked for me, so sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue while upgrading. previously I done the setup using postCSS.

official documentation says

`Note that Tailwind CSS v3.0 requires PostCSS 8, and no longer supports PostCSS 7. If you can’t upgrade to PostCSS 8, we recommend using Tailwind CLI instead of installing Tailwind as a PostCSS plugin.`

So this time i done the setup using cli. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

1. `yarn remove tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
   `yarn add --dev tailwindcss@latest @tailwindcss/typography@latest @tailwindcss/forms@latest @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio@latest @tailwindcss/line-clamp@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`
2. `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/css/style.css -o ./src/assets/css/tailwind.css --watch`

And in package.json need to do this change

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#it-just-isn-t-working-properly

my package.json

`"start": "concurrently \"npm run start:css\" \"react-scripts start\"",`
 `"start:css": "tailwindcss -o src/assets/css/tailwind.css --watch",`
 `"build": "tsc && npm run build:css && react-scripts build",`
`"build:css": "NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss -o src/assets/css/tailwind.css -m",`

This answer helped me to resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/70492649/7225816

Answer (score 1):

Yarn equivalent for those who are stuck with PostCSS v8 due to using a framework like Vuepress v1:

`yarn add -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall Tailwind and re-install using the compatibility build instead:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Answer (score 1):

npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

Answer (score 1):

You gotta uninstall the tailwindcss, postcss, and autoprefixer and then install the compatible versions:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and did the following to resolve;

1. Check your npm version using npm -ver, and make sure to install the latest version
2. Also check your Node version and update to the latest version through this URL: "https://nodejs.org/en/download/"

Answer (score 0):

While not using Vue, I hope this helps others with a similar issue. In my case, I was using TailwindCSS with Gulp (^4.0.2) and was able to solve the error by removing tailwind and its dependencies:

`npm uninstall tailwindcss gulp-postcss autoprefixer`

Then installed them again but explicitly specified the postcss plugin as version 9:

`npm install tailwindcss autoprefixer gulp-postcss@9`

I tried with `gulp-postcss@latest`, but found it kept installing version 8.3.1 and didn't resolve the error. More information can be seen here: https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users

Otherwise, I would echo the use of the Tailwind compatibility version.

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall tailwindcss
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution in case someone has exhausted all the other answers mentioned here. I removed the `tailwind.config.js` file and re-created it with  `npm tailwindcss init` and re-applied my modifications. Solved the issue for me!