# Getting error on npm run build (PostCSS plugin postcss-purgecss requires PostCSS 8) vuejs3 and tailwind

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm building an app using vuejs3 and tailwindcss

I was testing some configurations before starting the project then I got this error

`npm run build` throws:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                2:48:15 PM

 error  in ./src/styles/index.css

Error: PostCSS plugin postcss-purgecss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users


 @ ./src/main.js 9:0-28
 @ multi ./src/main.js

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-vue-env@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-vue-env@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

And here is my `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.0.0",
        "@fullhuman/vue-cli-plugin-purgecss": "~4.0.2",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.2.8",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925926/error-postcss-plugin-tailwindcss-requires-postcss-8)

Comment: OP does not list react. create-react-app what makes you run postcss 7 and tailwindcss with postcss-7-compat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build) you should do:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

then

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Note : to avoid any issue you could delete the `package-lock.json` then run the commands above.

Comment: I know what you are saying but my problem is not with `tailwind` its with the `postcss-purgecss` and my postcss version is 8

Comment: please share your tailwind.config.js file

Comment: According to the comments here  https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3575 you may need to escape ^ by adding \ before each instance, so the code would be ```npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@\^7 autoprefixer@\^9```

Answer (score 1):

OP does not list react in the dependencies. Those documentation links deal with `create-react-app` that makes you run `postcss@^7` and `tailwindcss` with `postcss-7-compat` release.

`npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest` will build just fine with Vue 3.

I suggest you remove the two `@fullman` packages, kill your `package.lock` (assuming using `npm` vs `yarn`) and `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again. `postcss` and `tailwindcss` packages will pull in the proper `postcss-purgecss` package.

Post your tailwind config and your builder config (webpack, rollup, gulp, etc) if you are still having issues.

Answer (score -1):

It is because tailwind does not support postcss version 8 as of now (I am talking about tailwind compat). You can found out more about this on this [official link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app#install-tailwind-via-npm) from tailwind. Basically it says that, postcss 8 is not supported by other libraries and therefore, tailwind uses postcss7-compat until more people start using postcss 8.