# Setting up Tailwind in Nuxt 3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I am having trouble setting up nuxt 3 and when I run dev server I keep getting this error, I followed the install instructions step by step from the tailwind docs.

`ERROR Cannot restart nuxt:  postcss@8 is not compatible with current version of nuxt (0.0.0). Expected: >=2.15.3`

````
at Object.postcss8Module (node_modules/@nuxt/postcss8/dist/index.js:19:11)
  at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:398:20)
  at async initNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1334:7)
  at async load (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6741:9)
  at async _applyPromised (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6693:10)```

Could someone please help I am lost.
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66582652/8172857

Comment: Update the nuxt , I think it is not the correct version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nuxtjs v3 and Tailwindcss v3 PostCSS@8 not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302520/nuxtjs-v3-and-tailwindcss-v3-postcss8-not-compatible)

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to uninstall @nuxt/postcss8.