# Vue tailwind project won't run postcss error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, postcss

I am trying to run my project on my laptop, it works on all other devices, has same code but for some reason I can't run tailwind on it, I am getting the following error

```
 in ./src/components/Adventures/Points.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3e2b19af&scoped=true&lang=sass

Syntax Error: Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Object.fromEntries is not a function

(@/home/dawid/Desktop/Project/postcss.config.js)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)


 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!
```

postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you please share your installed postcss and autoprefixer versions?

Comment: @AtifZia "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",     "postcss": "^7.0.36",

Answer (score 1):

Recently had the same issue when installing tailwindcss v3 with Vue 3 scaffolded using `@vue/cli`, but when using Vite installing it by tailwindcss [framework guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/framework-guides) works perfectly.

I've tried to configuring it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925926/error-postcss-plugin-tailwindcss-requires-postcss-8?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer by @Ram. Follow the instruction installing it with [Tailwind CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), then try to edit your scripts in `package.json`, for example:

```json
"scripts": {
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/tailwind.css -o ./src/assets/output.css",
    "serve": "npm run tailwind && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "npm run tailwind && vue-cli-service build"
  },
```

If you want to use the `--watch` from tailwind CLI tool to render every changes, run the script with **different terminal**.

```json
"scripts": {
    "tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/tailwind.css -o ./src/assets/output.css --watch",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
```

And **don't forget** to import the output css in your main views.

```html
<style>
  @import "./assets/tailwind.css";
  @import "./assets/output.css";

  ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error here.

`package.json`

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
  "autoprefixer": "^9",
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "postcss": "^7.0.36",
  "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
  "vue": "^2.6.11"
},
```

`postcss.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

`Component`

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center items-center text-sm">
    new component
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from "vue";

  export default Vue.extend({
    name: "NewComponent"
  });

</script>

<style scoped src="@/assets/tailwind.css">

</style>
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error2:40:19 PM

error  in ./src/assets/tailwind.css?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2312385a&scoped=true&lang=css&shadow

Syntax Error: Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Object.fromEntries is not a function

(@/home/vsts/work/1/s/postcss.config.js)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)


@ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--6-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-3!./src/assets/tailwind.css?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2312385a&scoped=true&lang=css&shadow 4:14-355
@ ./src/assets/tailwind.css?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2312385a&scoped=true&lang=css&shadow
@ ./src/components/NewComponent.vue?shadow
@ ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/entry-wc.js
```

Comment: I fixed it by upgrading npm version