# PostCSS 8 Error When Installing Tailwind CSS in Vue 3 (v3.2.10) without Vite (PostCSS 8 is supported)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I'm using Vue [version 3.2.10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue/v/3.2.10) **without Vite** and trying to install [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) version [2.2.14 (latest)](http://npm%20i%20tailwindcss@2.2.13).

**IMPORTANT: Vue version 3.0.6 began supporting PostCSS 8** (see 3rd point in the [GitHub documentation for the update](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#306-2021-02-24), under "features")

After carefully following installation instructions, then running `npm run serve` I keep getting this error:

```
error  in ./src/assets/main.css

Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-4",
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "firebase": "^8.9.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.4",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.14"
  }
```

As noted above, Vue 3.0.6 and beyond definitely support PostCSS 8. Also, the Tailwind CSS instructions for "*[PostCSS 7 compatibility build](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build)*" do NOT work.

After following those instructions, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: postcss@7.0.36
npm ERR! node_modules/postcss
npm ERR!   dev postcss@"^7" from the root project
npm ERR!   postcss@"^7.0.32" from autoprefixer@9.8.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/autoprefixer
npm ERR!     dev autoprefixer@"^9" from the root project
npm ERR!     autoprefixer@"^9.8.6" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!       peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.13
npm ERR!       node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel
npm ERR!         dev @vue/cli-plugin-babel@"~4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@vue/cli-plugin-router, @vue/cli-plugin-vuex, the root project)
npm ERR!     1 more (tailwindcss)
npm ERR!   42 more (@intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer postcss@"^8.0.0" from postcss-cli@8.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/postcss-cli
npm ERR!   dev postcss-cli@"^8.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/mgav/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mgav/.npm/_logs/2021-09-08T21_09_08_052Z-debug.log
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

It seems the problem (in some cases, anyway) is not directly linked to VueJS, but vue-cli instead.

The solution that worked for me is:

1. Update @vue/cli to "^5.0.0-beta.3" (was on "~4.5.0") - ([link to that on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli/v/5.0.0-beta.3))
2. Updated @vue/compiler to latest stable - ([link to that - 3.2.11 right now - on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/compiler-sfc/v/3.2.11))
3. Even though I wasn't using the postcss7-compat version, I followed the post's instructions to uninstall via `npm uninstall tailwindcss @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat`
4. Reinstalled latest versions of TailwindCSS, PostCSS and AutoPrefixer via `npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`

That's it!

*Note: This is **not my work**. I was directed by [Lindsay Wardell](https://twitter.com/lindsaykwardell) (@lindsaykwardell) to [a post on this Vuejs forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-3-postcss-8/112492) with the solution by [Thomas Castelly](https://forum.vuejs.org/u/shenron) (also no StackOverflow handle).*

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with the latest stable packages of `vue-cli` (v4.5.13 right now).

It look like that your issue is more about managing the dependencies *(you should give a read on [node.dev](https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version) about this topic)* as basically, to use TailwindCSS with the latest Vue3 stable version only require to install the latest version of the dependencies with few command lines and it work without the box.

As example, you will find below the instructions to create a minimal Vue3/Tailwind project which works as is:

```
$ vue create vue3-tailwindcss
$ cd vue3-tailwindcss
$ npm install -D @vue/compiler-sfc tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
$ npm run serve
```

Version of node and Vue :

```
$ node --version
v16.5.0
$ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.13
```

About your issue, you could have used the following method to get it working with with latest stables packages :

In `package.json` make theses changes :

- `"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0"` => `"@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13"`
- `"vue": "^3.0.0"` => `"vue": "^3.2.11"`
- `"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0"` => `"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.11"`

Then remove the file `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`.

Comment: Thank you @flydev. I'm out of my depth and don't plan to mess with what's finally working. I'll wait regarding answers here to see what much more experienced users have to say.

Comment: I edited my answer for clarification - no problem - waiting for "experienced users" :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution without Vite.

You can start a new project using a newer version of Vue CLI. Just reinstall it like:

```
npm uninstall -g @vue/cli
npm install -g @vue/cli@next
```

And create a new Vue 3 project. It will support PostCSS 8 without any problem.

Then follow the [Tailwind 3 installation guide using PostCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss). Don't forget to include your `*.vue` files in `tailwind.config.js`.

And you are ready to go.

**Look at [this repo I built](https://github.com/noxware/vue3-tailwind3-vuecli) as a guide.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are having that same issue, uninstall tailwind CSS postcss and autoprefixer. See the command below:

`npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

Then install it with the command below :

`npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`