# PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I keep getting the error below when trying to install Tailwind with Vue.js:

> Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.

I've tried several answers from [Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925926/error-postcss-plugin-tailwindcss-requires-postcss-8/68605148#68605148), including:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
vue add tailwind
```

And

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

But nothing works. My `package.json` includes:

```
"dependencies": {
  "postcss": "^8.4.20",
  "tailwindcss": "^3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.11",
  "postcss-cli": "^8.0.0",
  "sass": "^1.56.2",
  "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
  "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~3.0.0"
}
```

I use `Node 14.5.0`.

Any suggestion as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: need to update your PostCSS installation to version 8 or higher. Do `npm install postcss@^8`

Comment: I already had `postcss v8.4.20`, sorry for not making that clear - just updated my question. Problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to update the `@vue/cli` and all its plugins to the `newest version (5.0.0-rc.1)`, maybe the versions you have installed use PostCSS 7.

Comment: I installed vue CLI 5 and the problem was still there. However, from there I uninstall Tailwind and reinstalled it, and this time it worked. Something weird going on with Tailwind I think. Anyway thanks a lot!